# Tracking Issues across multiple repositories

Tags: github, jira, microservices

We often have epic stories which span multiple repositories.  I am looking for a mechanism to track all the work that is associated with a single story.  GitHub has Issues which is a close to the solution I seek.  The problem with Issues is they do not span multiple repositories. On deployment day I still need to scan ~10 repositories (there are 100 repo's, 10 are commonly used) to discover which ones have commits related to the story.

As a manual workaround I create multiple Issues.  One Issue for each repository.  Then I manually list the Issue#'s related to the epic story in Jira.

Is there a tool or alternative technique I can use to automatically combine these issues and treat them as one?

Comment: Found something useful for Trello users: http://goto.project-a.com/multiple-repositories-github-trello/ . Not going to work for me in a Jira environment.

Comment: I see you're using GitHub Issues together with JIRA, which seems unusual to me. Why can't you track issues in JIRA, which already works across repositories?

Comment: @Chris - I need to track git commits made to an issue exactly like github issues does.  I do not know of a way to do this with Jira issues.  Do you?

Comment: Yes: https://help.github.com/articles/integrating-jira-with-your-projects/. When properly configured, commits that mention an issue will show up in the issue and you can use text like `Closes PROJ-XX` to close issues by commits. Unfortunately, I don't think GitHub links back to JIRA though.

Comment: @Chris that link u posted has a reference to a youtube video describing Jira and Github integration.  That's exactly what Im looking for.  If u want to post some kind of answer regarding all this Ill mark it.  What you said in the comments pretty well sums it up.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful, Brian. I've added a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a bit unusual to use both JIRA and GitHub Issues together. JIRA offers virtually everything that GitHub Issues does and more.

[This guide](https://help.github.com/articles/integrating-jira-with-your-projects/) from GitHub shows how you can integrate JIRA directly with GitHub, skipping Issues altogether. When properly configured you will see links to GitHub in mentioned JIRA issues. You can also trigger JIRA workflow changes based on keywords in your commit messages, much like GitHub Issues does out of the box.